# duplicates to be removed sql

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I have in database records

[image]

My sql:

```
    SELECT
    DISTINCT name, date(mod_wr)
FROM
    test.object_stg
WHERE
    ir = '4552724'
GROUP BY
    name, date(mod_wr)
ORDER BY name
```

The last record is the same as the last but one. It has only a different date.
Is it possible to somehow query to return all records where there has been a change in the "name" column?
For record 4 and 5 there is the same name, only a different date. I would like it to return only a record of 4 and 5, because there was no change.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? PL/SQL is Oracle's in-database programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to remove rows where values are resused. E.g. your line #2, you can use `LAG()` and then only include rows where the value is different to the previous. E.g.

```
select name, date(mod_wr) from
(
    SELECT
        name, mod_wr, lag(name) over(order by mod_wr) as prev_name
    FROM
        test.object_stg
    WHERE
        ir = '4552724'
)
WHERE prev_name IS NULL OR name <> prev_name
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data, you have 3 distinct names. However, you cannot use distinct in your select statement because it applies to every field listed and none of the dates would provide an exact match.

However, you can use a group by statement in order to collate your titles together.

```
// MySQL 5.6 Statement
select name, date(mod_wr) from object_stg group by name;
// MSSQL 2017 Statement
select name, max(mod_wr) from object_stg group by name;
```

Both statements return 3 lines with just the BMW, 1.0 GL and 1.0 GLS showing with a single date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2060/2)